# How to write an event to specific calendar on live connect outlook calendars?

Tags: c#, events, calendar

I'm exploring the Live Connect SDK.

I can create calendar and read events, and even create new events using the `Microsoft.Live` library.

After I created a calendar say `[Programming calendar]` I wanted to write an event to it.

However all my attempts have failed to link the event to the newly created calendar i.e. `[Programming calendar]`.

So I was reading the SDK documentations and found the following:

> Updating calendar properties in C#
>   To change info for an existing calendar The `wl.calendars_update` scope is required.
>   - Use the `wl.events_create` scope to create Event objects on the user's **default calendar only**
>   - Use `wl.calendars_update` to create Event objects on **any** of the user's calendars

My code for creation was:

```
private async Task editEvent()
{
    if (!connected)
    {
 try
                {
                    var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
                    LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.calendars", "wl.calendars_update" });
                    //"wl.skydrive, wl.skydrive_update", 
                    if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                    {
                        var eventToPost = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                     eventToPost.Add("name", "my new event");

                     eventToPost.Add("calendar_id", "calendar.136c10ca65544801.99c35f9a9fb341a3af35daa82f4569f8");

                     eventToPost.Add("description", "this should be 2nd calendar");
                     eventToPost.Add("start_time", "2014-09-10T01:30:00-08:00");
                     eventToPost.Add("end_time", "2014-09-12T03:00:00-08:00");
                     eventToPost.Add("location", "business placeeeeeee");
                     eventToPost.Add("is_all_day_event", false);
                     eventToPost.Add("availability", "busy");
                     eventToPost.Add("visibility", "public");

                        this.session = result.Session;
                        connected = true;
                        this.connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
                        var meResult = await connectClient.PostAsync("me/events", eventToPost);

                        meData = meResult.Result;

                    }
                }
                catch (LiveAuthException ex)
                {
                    infoTextBlock.Text += ex.Data + " .autexception.." + ex.Message;
                    // Display an error message.
                }
                catch (LiveConnectException ex)
                {
                    infoTextBlock.Text += ex.Data + " .conExcception.." + ex.Message;
                    // Display an error message.
                }
}

}
```

and my code for update was:

```
private async Task editEvent()
{
    if (!connected)
    {
        try
        {
            var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
            LiveLoginResult result = await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.calendars", "wl.calendars_update" });

            if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                var eventToPost = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                eventToPost.Add("name", "program my c# - 2nd trial");

                eventToPost.Add("calendar_id", "calendar.136c10ca65544801.99c35f9a9fb341a3af35daa82f4569f8");

                eventToPost.Add("description", "this should be 2nd calendar");
                eventToPost.Add("start_time", "2014-09-10T01:30:00-08:00");
                eventToPost.Add("end_time", "2014-09-12T03:00:00-08:00");
                eventToPost.Add("location", "business placeeeeeee");
                eventToPost.Add("is_all_day_event", false);
                eventToPost.Add("availability", "busy");
                eventToPost.Add("visibility", "public");

                this.session = result.Session;

                connected = true;
                this.connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);

                var meResult = await connectClient.PutAsync("event.136c10ca6a355671.5f21a7994c7e40fd800bc48dcc07300b.991d1912ec6b4523a0f08839992aa2bb", eventToPost);

                meData = meResult.Result;
            }
        }
        catch (LiveAuthException ex)
        {
            // Display an error message.
        }
        catch (LiveConnectException ex)
        {
            // Display an error message.
            infoTextBlock.Text += ex.Data + " ..." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine except that it will never change the calendar ID property and it will use the default calendar ID.

So researching the documentations on the [REST reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#event) I found the following fact !!
[image: event object]

so there is a discrepancy in the documentations bec. the table says the calendar_id is readonly 
and they claims that you can write to any calendar using the correct scope " Use `wl.calendars_update` to create Event objects on **any** of the user's calendars  "

One more things I confirmed that in my newly created calendar [Programming calendar] the permission property I am the owner !

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I discovered where i was wrong:

//this line is useless since the property is readOnly

```
eventToPost.Add("calendar_id", "calendar.136c10ca65544801.99c35f9a9fb341a3af35daa82f4569f8");
```

//this is the wrong line [ wrong path]

```
var meResult = await connectClient.PostAsync("me/events", eventToPost);
```

//this is the correct way [proper path use]i.e. replace "me" by "CALENDAR_ID"

```
var meResult = await connectClient.PostAsync("calendar.136c10ca65544801.99c35f9a9fb341a3af35daa82f4569f8/events", eventToPost);
```

referrence for this solution :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/15207829-4999-46d9-a835-e350526f3aa

Comment: please see my question and give me answer.
on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/cab14949-b23a-4b71-8591-78d4696c9900/subscribe-calendar-using-liveconnect-client?forum=messengerconnect#cab14949-b23a-4b71-8591-78d4696c9900

Comment: I did alreay. best luck

Comment: thanks for replying back I have another issue see it on question link.